# Merge sort using inplace merging

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, mergesort

A[]  ->  1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8      //

lb=0,mid-1=3,mid+1=4,ub=7;

a=3,b=7,ab=7;

1st iteration

a=3,b=6,ab=6;

---

2nd iteration

swap(A[ab],A[a])  // int t; t i'll using for temporary storage

1 3 5 6 2 4 7 8

b=5,ab=5;
 sort(A,lb,mid-1);  // using bubble sort

---

3rd iteration

swap(A[ab],A[a])

1 3 5 4  2 6 7 8

b=5,ab=4

sort(A,lb,mid-1) // using bubble sort

---

Is this correct approach for Merge sort using inplace merging. This is my first attempt about inplace merging.If it is not correct approach  someone can suggest me.

Comment: why are you mixing bubble sort in merge sort?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that you have Mergesort algorithm.

Using Mergesort at first phase you need to split you array into subarrays.

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8]

A1 = [1, 3, 5, 7], A2 = [2, 4, 6, 8]

A11 = [1,3], A12 = [5,7], A21 = [2,4], A22 = [6,8]
... // till you have an arrays looks like this:
A1 = [1], A2 = [3], A3 = [5], A4 = [7], A5 = [2], A6 = [4], A7 = [6], A8 = [8]
```

Then you merging in reverse order, and compare only first elements in both arrays (put lowest element in new array).

```
[1,3], [5,7], [2,4], [6,8]
  [1,3,5,7],   [2,4,6,8]
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```